# Java how does the stack class violate the rule of substitutability and the notion of encapsulation

Tags: java, encapsulation, stack

I don't understand. I know it has to do with stacks not being vectors. Can someone explain this.

I would guess its not substitutable because stacks aren't vectors. So if you have a situation that use vectors you won't be able to use a stack. The second part is a guess but since if you were to create a private class then you wouldn't know how the class is being used and might try to implement it as a vector.

Comment: Be clear. why do you think that `stack class violate the rule of substitutability and the notion of encapsulation`?

Comment: I would guess its not substitutable because stacks aren't vectors. So if you have a situation that use vectors you won't be able to use a stack. The second part is a guess but since if you were to create a private class then you wouldn't know how the class is being used and might try to implement it as a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only true if you insist that `Stack` models a stack and nothing else. As it stands, `Stack` allows stack-y operations and, in addition, vector-y random-access operations. It may be a stack on steroids, but it's still a stack.

Compare that with a class named `LinkedList` that also supports methods needed for a LIFO stack. Does that make it a non-list?

As an aside, note that `Stack` and `Vector` have been out of use since year 1998.